# How to play two audio files from the iPod library simultaneously?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avfoundation, mpmediapickercontroller

I know that the MediaPickerConroller can be used to access the iPod library, however I'm not sure that it can play two songs at the same time.  AVFoundation would allow this, but then how do you get AVFoundation to access the library?  Is there an easier way of doing this? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way - though not exactly an easy way - to play more than one audio files at the same time is to use an Audio Processing Graph. "MixerHost", the example app by Apple, is a good starting point. "AudioGraph" (https://github.com/tkzic/audiograph) has more functionality than you want, but the manual is helpful to understand the basics of audio processing graphs.

The MediaPickerConroller will allow you to select more than one item from the iTunes library. You will have to get the list of URLs from the media picker and connect them to the graph yourself.